# Google App Engine Mail API doesn't include headers when sending outgoing message

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send an email with a header via GAE Mail API. I set a header:

```
message.setHeader("X-Priority", "1");
```

But AppEngine ignores it. And when I receive an email it doesn't contain a priority header.

Does anybody know how can I set the priority header for outgoing emails?

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?

Answer (score 4):

[The Google App Engine Mail API only supports the specific headers listed in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/mail-with-headers-attachments), currently:

- In-Reply-To
- List-Id
- List-Unsubscribe
- On-Behalf-Of
- References
- Resent-Date
- Resent-From
- Resent-To

Comment: To add to that, in testing the MailHandler in JavaMail 1.5.3, adding the `auto-submitted` header caused GAE to not deliver the email at all.